# How can I use htaccess to redirect paths with a wildcard character in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

I recently changed my 92 category links and now I am getting hit with hundreds of 404 errors from Google because the old links are not found.  I tried  to use plugins to automatically redirect single URLS but I am noticing there are more and more coming in and doing everything on a 1 by 1 basis is not efficient.

I was hoping someone could assist me on getting my pages redirected using my htaccess file.

For Example Going to

```
example.com/category/old-category/
```

should redirect to

```
example.com/category/new-category/
```

More importantly I would like to redirect the page numbers of the old categories to the page numbers of the new categories using a wildcard. So page x of old category will redirect to page x of new category.

```
example.com/category/old-category/page/5/
```

should redirect to

```
example.com/category/new-category/page/5/
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this generic redirect rule just below `RewriteEngine` line:

```
RewriteRule ^(category)/old-category(/.*)? /$1/new-category/$2 [L,NC,R=301]
```